# Cannot get my SQL to delete all records in a table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm very new to using VBA within but what I need to do is simply delete all of the records in a table.

I have first created a module and have the following code within it:

```
Function DeleteRecords()

DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM [7 FUF]"

End Function
```

I then create a macro which has one command, `RunCode`.
The Function Name that is passed to this command is `DeleteRecords()`. When I start to type in to the function name section, it does suggest `DeleteRecords`, so I'm confident it's seeing the function.

When running the macro, I get the error

> The expression you entered has a function name that Microsoft Access
>   can't find

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't the correct syntax `Delete from [Table]` ? (without the asterisk)

Comment: @PSVSupporter I think MS Access permits the `*` there unconventionally. I had to look it up. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177896%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: Is it a public function?

Comment: Where's the function located and where are you calling it from?

Comment: Sorry not sure about where it's located but if I hit Alt+F11 to get into the VBA view and I can see the module in the hierachy along with other modules that work within the database. I am calling it from a macro.

Comment: OK i think i've got it. It seems that I can't name the fucnction "DeleteRecords" It must be a naming conflict within Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the problem is not from the function. I believe your `module` and your `function` have the same name hence a conflict. If they do, make sure you change the `module`'s name to something else like:  DeleteRecordsMod. 
It is a known and common issue in access. Also make sure the function is publicly accessible. 
In your code, you don't really need * for delete everything

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM [7 FUF]"
```

- [Delete Documentation - Vba - Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845201.aspx)
- [Can't find function issue - vba](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/860068-cant-find-function-macro)

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider bypassing a macro entirely, and doing something like:

CurrentDB.Execute "DELETE * FROM [table]"

Or

Create a DELETE query and store it in the DB, then do a DoCmd.OpenQuery